# Как сортировать массив по дате

Tags: php, массивы, yii2, сортировка

Делаю выборку следующим образом

```
//ищем в news и ThisDay и сливаем два массива вместе
$mergeResult = array_merge(
    //выборка из таблицы thisDay
    ThisDay::find()
            ->where(
                    new Expression(
                    "day = :dateDay"
                    . " AND id_region = :id_region", [":dateDay" => 
$dateDay,
                ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
            ->orderBy("news_date DESC")
            ->all(),
    //поиск по таблице News с лимитом 4 - (минус) кол-во новостей в ThisDay
    News::find()
            ->alias("n")
            ->where(
                    //выборка по дню
                    new Expression("EXTRACT(DAY FROM cdate) = :userDay "
//                                                выборка по региону,
                    . "AND id_region = :id_region "
//                                                выборка по месяцу,
                    . "AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cdate) = :userMonth "
//                                                выборка по году,
                    . "AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate) "
//                                                выборка по статусу,
                    . "AND status > :stat AND n.id NOT IN"
                    //и чтобы id не совпадало с id из таблицы this_day
                    . " (SELECT id_news FROM this_day)",
                    //агрументы для бандинга
                    [":userDay" => $dateDay,
                ":userMonth" => $currentMoth,
                ":id_region" => REGION_ID,
                ":stat" => 1]))
            //новости с самым высоким рейтингом
            ->joinWith("rating nr")
            ->orderBy("nr.rate DESC")
            ->limit(4 - ThisDay::find()
                    ->where(
                            new Expression(
                            "day = :dateDay"
                            . " AND id_region = :id_region", [":dateDay" => 
$dateDay,
                        ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
                    ->count())
            //группировка и сортировка по дате
            ->orderBy("cdate_int DESC")
            ->groupBy("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate)")
            ->all());
```

Получаю массив, далее индексирую его

```
//индексирую, если ThisDay
$indexedThisDay = ArrayHelper::index($mergeResult, function ($element) {
            if ($element instanceof ThisDay) {
                return (int) \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($element['news_date'], 'yyyy');
            }
        });
//индексирую, если News
$indexedNews = ArrayHelper::index($mergeResult, function ($element) {
            if ($element instanceof News) {
                return (int) \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($element['cdate_int'], 'yyyy');
            }
        });
```

Затем сортирую его примерно так `arsort($model, SORT_NUMERIC);` был еще вот такой вариант 
`$model = array_merge($indexedNews, $indexedThisDay);`
и затем опять `arsort($model, SORT_NUMERIC);`

получаю массив с ключами 
`int(1) "0" int(1) "1" int(1) "2" int(1) "3"` в в которых год расположен 
`2017, 2016, 2017, 2016` или `2016, 2017, 2016, 2017` как можно отсортировать массив так, чтобы они встали по убыванию даты? Чтобы получилось `2016, 2016, 2017, 2017`. Т.е элементы не сортируются по убыванию/возрастанию вместе, они это делают каждый отдельно, а нужно, чтобы они отсортировались как один массив.

UPD: Я пытался использовать это

```
$model = array_merge($indexedNews, $indexedThisDay);

usort($model, function($arr1, $arr2) {
    $dateThisDay = strtotime($arr1['news_date']);
    $dateNews = strtotime($arr2['cdate_int']);

    if ($dateThisDay == $dateNews)
        return 0;

    return ($dateThisDay < $dateNews) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Но получаю ошибку Getting unknown property: ************\News::news_date поле news_date принадлежит ThisDay а он его ищет в News

Comment: зачем вы сначала сливаете два массива, а потом разделяете?

Comment: @teran мне необходимо переиндексировать массив по дате, чтобы корректно отобразить ее в представлении в последовательности, например: "1 год назад 1 год назад 2 года назад 2 года назад", сейчас у меня не получается отсортировать эти два массива после повторного смерживания так, словно они один массив, все функции применяются сначала к одному массиву, потому ко второму и все равно получается 1 2 1 2

Comment: @teran можно наверное обойтись и без разделения и сделать сортировку сразу, просто я не знаю как)

Comment: @teran я уточнил свой код, чтобы было понятно для чего разделяю

Comment: Вы же разные массивы сливаете - походу придется по отдельности сортировать, у вас же в любом случае 2 колонки выходит? А дальше уже можно от одного другой проверить циклом.

Comment: @And два разных массива и ключи для сортировка разные, т.к названия полей разные, а данные в них по формату совпадают( Что вы имеете ввиду под `А дальше уже можно от одного другой проверить циклом`?

Comment: Ну так если они разные, то зачем вообще пытаться сортировать разные данные в одном?

Comment: @And потому что в представлении они должны выводится по порядку, отсортированные по дате, а без сортировки получается сначала либо один массив вначале, либо другой

Comment: Ну когда происходит сливание, то и ключи у вас идут так-же по порядку, а это значит, что при каждой итерации, будет браться ключ по порядку, а вы берете сразу 2, если бы у вас шли массивы в слитом с 2 ключами - тогда да, вы бы могли написать вызов обоих ключей, но опять-же по ключу массива который возвращает итерация. Попробуйте написать условие, если есть ключ `news_date`, значит `ThisDay`, если есть ключ `cdate_int`, значит это `news`.

Comment: @And я могу сделать ($arr instanceof ThisDay) и это вернут true или false, а что потом делать потом?

Comment: Это массив, со строками, а не объектами. Вы только и дело, можете проверить только ключи, если это объекты, я думаю сортировку можно было бы делать на уровне объектов. и в usort во 2-ом аргументе массиве, передавать первым значением объект или название класса, а вторым значением свойство.

Comment: @And вторым значением объект или названием класса, а вторым значением - свойство? Что то не пойму Вас

Comment: Дело в другом, вы сливаете 2 разных массива, значит это два разных ключа - что вернет `var_dump($model);` до `usort`? Добавьте в свой вопрос.

Comment: @And там огромный массив из 4 значений. Каждое значение - это куча полей и каких то внутренних настроек yii. Как лучше будет добавить? Картинкой или скрытым кодом? (добавлю завтра только)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам поможет этот алгоритм сортировки:

```
function sortBy( $field, $array ) {
            usort( $array, function ( $item1, $item2 )use( $field ) {

                if ( $item1[ $field ] == $item2[ $field ] ) return 0;
                return $item1[ $field ] < $item2[ $field ] ? -1 : 1;
            } );
            return true;
        }
```

Где:

- `$field` - это ключ по которому хотите отсортировать
- `$array` - исходный массив

Comment: Уже давно есть `function() {...}` - `create_function`, можно забыть как страшный сон.

Comment: @And это я писал по старой памяти )) , обновил ответ.

Comment: @Арсен а как я могу улучшить эту функцию, в случае, если у меня не один $field а несколько, т.к для разных $item1 и $item2 названия полей для сортировка различаются)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев одновременно вы вряд ли сможете сортировать по нескольким ключам. Но можно по отдельности сортировать, вырезать нужные ключ=>значение и делать array_push в новый массив

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = [
    0 => 2017,
    1 => 2016,
    2 => 2017,
    3 => 2016
];

asort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC); //по возрастанию, сохраняя ключи 
sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC); //по возрастанию, не сохраняя ключи 
arsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC); //по убыванию, сохраняя ключи
rsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC); //по убыванию, не сохраняя ключи

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: очевидно, год это не единственное значение массива